# Obscure Pygame Rect error

Tags: python, pygame, rect

I've seen some topics here with the error: "TypeError: Argument must be rect style object". I'm having this error endlessly.

I've read the docs:

```
Rect(left, top, width, height) -> Rect
Rect((left, top), (width, height)) -> Rect
Rect(object) -> Rect
```

I have a method to extract subsurfaces from a pygame.Surface (It uses the surface's original method):

```
def getSubSurface(self, rect):

    """
    Returns the subsurface of a specified rect area in the grict surface.
    """

    return self.surface.subsurface(rect)
```

The problem is when I pass this rect (I've "unclustered" the arguments to make it clearer):

```
sub = []
w = self.tileWidth
h = self.tileHeight
for i in range((self.heightInPixels/self.heightInTiles)):
    y = self.grid.getY(i)
    for j in range((self.widthInPixels/self.widthInTiles)):
        x = self.grid.getX(j)
        sub.append(self.tileset.getSubSurface(pygame.Rect(x,y,w,h)))
```

I've explicitly passed a valid pygame.Rect, and I'm blitting nothing nowhere, and I get:

```
sub.append(self.tileset.getSubSurface(pygame.Rect(x,y,w,h)))
TypeError: Argument must be rect style object
```

Now, the funny part is: If I change the arguments to arbitrary int values:

```
sub.append(self.tileset.getSubSurface((1,2,3,4)))
```

It works perfectly. The pygame subsurfaces method takes it as a valid Rect. Problem is: All my instance-variables are valid ints (Even if they were not, it does not work if I convert them explicitly).

It makes no sense.

Why it takes explicit ints, but does not take my variables? (If the values were of an incorrect type, I would not get a "rectstyle" error, as if I was passing arguments incorrectly).

Comment: create a temporary pygame.Rect variable, and use pdb to check at which x,y,w,h values this occurs.

Comment: Does `sub.append(self.tileset.getSubSurface(pygame.Rect((x,y,w,h))))` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs if any of the arguments passed to `Rect()` are not numeric values.

To see what's wrong, add the following code to your method:

```
import numbers
...
sub = []
w = self.tileWidth
h = self.tileHeight
for i in range((self.heightInPixels/self.heightInTiles)):
    y = self.grid.getY(i)
    for j in range((self.widthInPixels/self.widthInTiles)):
        x = self.grid.getX(j)
        # be 100% sure x,y,w and h are really numbers
        assert isinstance(x, numbers.Number)
        assert isinstance(y, numbers.Number)
        assert isinstance(w, numbers.Number)
        assert isinstance(h, numbers.Number)
        sub.append(self.tileset.getSubSurface(pygame.Rect(x,y,w,h)))
```

Comment: It was necessary to dig to find that it was a "NoneType" the problem. But the developer could not have predicted this and added a "NoneType in the argument error" (Probably the NoneType entered the "else" block of the code, and it was treated as a "rectstyle error").

Answer (score 0):

I've found the source of the problem. I've explicitly converted the variables to ints:

```
sub.append(self.tileset.getSubSurface((int(x),int(y),int(w),int(h))))
```

And got a "TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'" It became clear. The "x" and "y" variables in my iterations were returning a single "None" at the end (Because they were getting their values from a dictionary, and, since they stopped finding keys, they began returning a NoneType).

I've solved the problem fixing my getX and getY methods:

```
def getX(self, pos):

    """
    The getX() method expects a x-key as an argument. It returns its equivalent value in pixels.
    """

    if self.x.get(pos) != None:
        return self.x.get(pos)
    else:
        return 0 # If it is NoneType, it returns an acceptable Rect int value.
```